# Wireless not working with different subnet

Tags: networking

1.Internet Router ip 192.168.0.1 (LAN) - There are 3 more computers connect to this router (ip 192.168.0.2, 192.168.0.3, 192.168.0.4) .

2. Wireless Router connected to the internet router with ip 192.168.0.5 . The wireless Router send out DHCP ip range 192.168.1.1-100
3. Wireless printers connected to wireless router 192.168.1.1 .
4. All 3 computers can't add the printers !!! why ? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend changing the router mode on the wireless router from NAT mode to access point mode if it is possible. The clients on the wired network cannot access the printer behind the wireless router because of NAT or firewall policies.